# Show (related) Parent & Subcategory from WooCommerce Product Category Widget within (each) category page

Tags: woocommerce, code-snippets

I cannot applied below code when both conditional tag (is_product_category) together in product (and Child) category page and shop page.

Hope anyone can help.

My objective: Each product category page (include parent & child category page), the widget display all parent & child (semantic related) product categories (unrelated product category needed to hide in widget).

refer to [code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420094/hide-subcategories-from-woocommerce-category-widget) and also [code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529109/show-children-for-subcategory-archives-in-woocommerce-product-category-widget)

```js
//* Used when the widget is displayed as a dropdown
add_filter('woocommerce_product_categories_widget_dropdown_args', 'appliances', 10, 10);
//* Used when the widget is displayed as a list
add_filter('woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'appliances', 10, 10);
function appliances($cat_args) {
  if (is_product_category(75) || is_product_category($termchildren)) {
    // Create an array that will hold the ids that need to be included
    $include_terms = array();
    // Push the default term that you need to shown 
    array_push($include_terms, 75);
    // Create an array that will hold the ids that need to be included
    $termchildren = get_term_children(75, 'product_cat');
    }
  if (is_product_category(59) || is_product_category($termchildren)) {
    // Create an array that will hold the ids that need to be included
    $include_terms = array();
    // Push the default term that you need to shown 
    array_push($include_terms, 59);
    // Create an array that will hold the ids that need to be included
    $termchildren = get_term_children(59, 'product_cat');
    }
    foreach($termchildren as $child) {
      $term = get_term_by('id', $child, 'product_cat');
      array_push($include_terms, $term - > term_id);
    }
    // Finally pass the array
    $cat_args['include'] = $include_terms;
  }
  return $cat_args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After many days trial and error, herewith the code snippet that worked for me:

1. Used multiple conditional tags;
2. Show only related category (&child) within each product category;
3. But don't know how add-in another filter woocommerce_product_categories_widget_dropdown_args for (if) checked dropdown product category widget;
4. Disadvantage: in the Product Category Widget "Only show children of the current category" cannot function. (Due to get_term_children as below code snippets).

Hope help anyone here and wish someone can improve this answer.

```
//* Used when the widget is displayed as an slug (aabc) / term_id (50) lists
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', function ( $cat_args ) {
if ( is_product_category('aabc') || is_product_category('ddef') || is_product_category('gghi') || is_product_category('jjkl') || is_product_category('mmno') || is_product_category('ppqr') || is_product_category('sstu') || is_product_category('vvwx') || is_product_category('yyz')){
        // Create an array that will hold the ids that need to be included
        $include_terms = array();
        // Push the default term that you need to show 
        array_push( $include_terms, 50 );
        // Create an array that will hold the ids that need to be included
        $termchildren = get_term_children( 50, 'product_cat' );
        // Iterate over the terms found and add it to the array which holds the IDs to include
        foreach( $termchildren as $child ) {
            $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, 'product_cat' );     
            array_push( $include_terms, $term->term_id );
            }
        // Finally pass the array
        $cat_args['include'] = $include_terms;
    }   
        return $cat_args;
    });
//* Used when the widget is displayed as an slug (abc) / term_id (60) lists
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', function ( $cat_args ) {
if ( is_product_category('abc') || is_product_category('def') || is_product_category('ghi') || is_product_category('jkl') || is_product_category('mno') || is_product_category('pqr') || is_product_category('stu') || is_product_category('vwx') || is_product_category('yz')){
        // Create an array that will hold the ids that need to be included
        $include_terms = array();
        // Push the default term that you need to show 
        array_push( $include_terms, 60 );
        // Create an array that will hold the ids that need to be included
        $termchildren = get_term_children( 60, 'product_cat' );
        // Iterate over the terms found and add it to the array which holds the IDs to include
        foreach( $termchildren as $child ) {
            $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, 'product_cat' );     
            array_push( $include_terms, $term->term_id );
            }
        // Finally pass the array
        $cat_args['include'] = $include_terms;
    }   
        return $cat_args;
    });
```